# Getting Uploaded filename Extension in Django View?

Tags: python, django

Im working through Alex Pale's minimal django file upload example for django 1.8 -

https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example/tree/master/src/for_django_1-8/myproject/myproject/myapp

I know how to get the file extension in the form, but how can I get this in the view. I'm aware I can access the file thru -

```
docfile=request.FILES['docfile']
```

View -

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from myproject.myapp.models import Document
from myproject.myapp.forms import DocumentForm


def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():     
            docfile=request.FILES['docfile']

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Form -

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file'
    )
```

Comment: `docfile=request.FILES['docfile']` line is already exists on the view itself. Don't know what exactly you want..

Comment: So docfile in the view is type - forms.FileField? So I could run - 
    docfile=request.FILES['docfile']
    content_type = docfile.content_type.split('/')[0]

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking for the extension try this:

```
>>> f = "this.that.ext"
>>> e = f.split(".")[-1]
>>> f
'this.that.ext'
>>> e
'ext'
>>>
```

You know how to get the complete filename.  What you want is the last string after the "."